# Changing the main image by clicking on a thumbnail in magento

Tags: jquery, magento-1.5, magento

i am trying to change the main product image when a thumbnail is clicked. I have also added zoom functionality to this main image. Most of the jquery gallery plugins set the entire image element through javascript. But i just want to set the src of the image element. How can i do this to get the desired behavior? 
Here is the code for my home page where i am trying to implement this :

```
<?php                                                                                                                                                                              
    $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');                                                                                                                                    
    $productId = $this->getProduct_id();                                                                                                                                           
    $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);  //load the product  
?>  
    <div class="home-product-container-main"> <!--Product main container div-->
    <div class="home-product-container-image">
    <script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    $('#image1').addimagezoom({
        zoomrange: [3, 10],
        magnifiersize: [575,300],
        magnifierpos: 'right',
        cursorshade: true,
        largeimage: '<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image')->constrainOnly(TRUE)->keepAspectRatio(TRUE)->resize(1000)?>' //<-- No comma after last option!
    })
</script> 
    <?php
    //$_img = '<a id="a_image" href="'.$_product->getProductUrl().'" title=""><img id="image". src="'.$this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image')->constrainOnly(TRUE)->keepAspectRatio(TRUE)->resize(325,251). '" alt="'.$this->htmlEscape($this->getImageLabel()).'" title="'.$this->htmlEscape($this->getImageLabel()).'"  /></a>';                                                           
    //echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_img, 'image');
    ?>
    <img id="image1" border="0" src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image')->constrainOnly(TRUE)->keepAspectRatio(TRUE)->resize(300,225)?>" style="width:300px;height:225px" />
    <div id="thumbs">
    <?php 
        $obj = new Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Media();
        $_product1 = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Product();
        // Load all product information of a particular product
        $Products_one = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
        // Use your Product Id instead of $id
        $countt = count($Products_one->getMediaGalleryImages());
        if($countt>0){
        foreach ($Products_one->getMediaGalleryImages() as $_image)
        {
        // For the Original Image
        echo "<img src=".Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA).str_replace(Mage::getBaseUrl('media'),"",$_image->url)." alt=''width='50' height='50' />";
        }
        }
    ?>  
     </div>
    </div>
```

In the above code, i want to set the src of the image element with id=image1 when a thumbnail is clicked.The thumbnails are displayed in the div with id=thumbs Thanks.

Comment: This is not a programming question - please change it to include some code

Comment: Is there a relationship between the thumb img name and the full size image name, or have you attached the full res img url to the thumbnail somehow? Your thumbnail image needs to know the url of the full size image. Example <img id="myimage.jpg" data-full-size-image="/image/full/bigimage.jpg" src="/image/thumb/smallimage.jpg" />